# I cannot use json result outside onResponse() in onReceive() - Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am new to Retrofit.
I have SmsListener class that extends Broadcast Receiver class this class for Listen to a message and when it is get the message it will do some operations on it.
and I am using Retrofit to read some json data from local host URL.
I want to get the JSON result from onResponse to use it in onReceive
I am defined an Array List to add json values from onResponse method.
but when I want to use this values in onReceive it is gives me tr_num: null
I do not know why that happen. but when I am trying to Log json values inside onResponse it is LOGED SUCCESSFULLY.
and I am getting what I want. but when I am trying to use this values in onReceive it is gives me tr_num: null This my SmsListener class

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;

public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

private SharedPreferences sp;

Context context;
String tr_number = "";
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.context = context;

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        if (bundle != null) {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                    Intent intentCall = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    getTransactionNumber();
                    Log.d("ArrayList ", "ArrayList item 1 = " + tr_num.get(1)); // not Loged out

                    if (msg_from.contains("+249")) {

                        if (msgBody.contains("1435892")) {
                            if (msgBody.contains("50")) {
                                // send Notification to user with success msg

                            }

                        } else {
                            // send Notification to user with error msg
                        }
                    } else {
                        // send Notification to user with DO NOT CHEAT MSG
                    }
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentCall, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    pendingIntent.send();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
 //                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

private String getAmount(String amount) {


    return "";
}

ArrayList<String> tr_num;

private void getTransactionNumber() {

    RegisterAPI2 registerAPI = ApiClient.getApiClient2().create(RegisterAPI2.class);

    //registerAPI.insertUser(msg, amount, tr_number, phone);
    Call<TrResponse> req = registerAPI.getTrNum();
    req.enqueue(new Callback<TrResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<TrResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<TrResponse> response) {

                        TrResponse post = response.body();
                        tr_num = new ArrayList<String>();

                        tr_num.add(post.getComment().toString());
                        tr_num.add(post.getTotalCost().toString());

                        Log.d("CallBack", " response is " + post.getComment().toString()); // successfully Loged out
                        Log.d("CallBack", " response is " + tr_num.get(1).toString()); // successfully Loged out
                        //Log.d("CallBack", " response is " + response.toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<TrResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                        Log.d("TTTT CallBack", " Throwable is " + t + " Call  " + call.toString());

                    }

                }
    );

  }
 }
```

and this is my interface

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

 public interface RegisterAPI2 {
 // String msg, String phone, String tr_number, String amount
 @GET("getTrNumber.php")
 Call<TrResponse> getTrNum();

 }
```

and this my TrResponse POJO Class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class TrResponse {

@SerializedName("Comment")
private String Comment;
@SerializedName("Number_of_people")
private String totalCost;

public String getTotalCost() {
    return totalCost;
}

public void setTotalCost(String totalCost) {
    this.totalCost = totalCost;
}

public TrResponse(String comment, String totalCost) {
    Comment = comment;
    this.totalCost = totalCost;
}

public String getComment() {
    return Comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    Comment = comment;
}
}
```

sorry for my English.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did my operation inside onResponse.
That solved my problem after 24 hours searching.